# Starting a new capybara session for every test

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am trying to start a new Capybara session for every one of our rspec tests and am unable to figure out how to properly quit/close the session on completion.

Here is my spec_helper.rb file.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.before :each do
      @session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
  end

 config.after :each do
     @session.driver.browser.quit
 end

end
```

The @session.driver.browser.quit statement properly closes the browser but for the last test that gets run I get an error message:

```
/Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/file_reaper.rb:32:in `reap': file not added for reaping: "/var/folders/5l/kw4vv8bj7rvc4xv6yfyspkwh0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20131107-96496-cx4x5r" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:45:in `quit'
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:58:in `ensure in quit'
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:58:in `quit'
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.37.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:168:in `quit'
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:140:in `quit'
from /Users/lpc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@capybara/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:17:in `block in browser'
```

I believe the problem is because Capybara is also quitting the browser at the conclusion of all the tests. Does anyone know the proper way to do this and how I can silence this error message? Thanks for any help.

====UPDATE=====

To close the loop on this, I posted to Capybara google group with my issue was fixed and merged into master.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/tZi2F306Fvo

Comment: Why do you want a new session for each test? Usually it is sufficient to just delete the cookies - eg using `@session.reset!` or by using capybara/rspec.

Comment: It's possible I'm thinking of this incorrectly but we're using capybara + webdriver/sauce. Sauce records videos of your tests. There is one video per driver instance, so I was trying to have one driver per test rather than simply clearing cookies for the driver. This way each test would have is own video with independent results.

Comment: I had the same issue. Try this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-capybara/RYkpdB6uUTA/7q8VxTMmN0QJ

Answer (score 8):

Try it with `Capybara.reset_session!`.

```
feature "my test" do    
  after { Capybara.reset_sessions! }
  
  scenario "my scenario" do
    # your assertions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I just encountered this problem. If you have a Capybara::Session, the browser stays open after each SPEC resulting in multiple browsers when you are running several SPEC files. There is no Capybara:Session quit method, so you need to get the driver object first then quit. I typically add this at the end of each SPEC file:

```
after :all do
  @capybara_session.driver.quit()
end
```

where @capybara_session is a Capybara::Session object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a sauce method that you can use to clip the recording, and call that in your `after` instead?

Instead of quitting after each test, perhaps you could quit before each one? If you get an error trying to exit before one is running, perhaps there is a way to see if one is already running? If not, you could do a horrible, nasty hack: set a global variable in an `after` that lets you know there is a driver that you can quit.

Comment: I tried quitting before each test. Smart idea. However, I still get the reap error. I think for every driver I open, it will quit that driver in an end hook, so regardless of when I run it, I will always get that reap error (this is just a guess)