# Routing constraint warden session with Devise and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I'm using Capybara for some feature tests and have added a routing constraint.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
class LenderConstraint
    def matches?(request)
        user_cookie = request.session.fetch('warden.user.user.key')
    end
end
```

This works properly but it's not available in the test environment. Everything was working properly with the tests up until the addition of this constraint. What's the most effective way to get this working?

**Update**

It works when I run the individual test but not when I run the suite.

**Update 2**

I've debugged the session and the issue is pertaining to  `warden.user.user.key` not being properly set. When I call:

`login_as(@user, scope: :user)` with a user ID of 1, the value of `request.session.fetch('warden.user.user.key')` returns 2 which is the ID of the first user the system logged in during the test suite.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to reset the session inbetween tests ...

`Capybara.reset_sessions!`

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26734459/316729